# append content of one file to another yaml file with indentation

Tags: linux, shell, yaml

I have two file, let say 'values.yaml' file with content:

```
env_configmap:
```

And file name 'env' with content:

```
###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_ENV=prod
APP_DEBUG=1
```

Now I want to append 'env' file to values.yaml with identation, finally, the content of values.yaml will be  likes:

```
env_configmap:
  ###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
  APP_ENV=prod
  APP_DEBUG=1
```

is there any commands or shell scripts could do that?

Comment: Your `env` file isn't a YAML file, and it doesn't make sense to append it to `values.yaml`: the result is is not going to be what you expect.

Comment: ya, I think I have to use a command to indent every line in 'env' before append to yaml file

Comment: No. The `env` file **does not contain valid syntax**. It doesn't matter how much you indent it. It's not a YAML file.

Answer (score 0):

I change my approach. I append space to each line of 'env' file and output to values.yaml by command

```
sed -e 's/^/ /' env >> values.yaml
```